# Django db model alternative in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, express, sequelize.js

I have a model in Django DB in python.

```
    id = models.BigAutoField(db_column='xxxxxxxxx', primary_key=True)  # 1
    xxxxxx = models.ForeignKey('xxxxx', db_column='xxxxxx', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)  # 2
    xxx_name = models.CharField(db_column='xxxxxx', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # 3
    state = models.CharField(db_column='State', max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)  # 4

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'xxxxxxx'
```

Which is dynamically creating join query or my SQL query based on a criteria

`selected_service_centres = class_name.objects.using('xxxxxx').only('id', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'address', 'xxxxx').filter(**conditions_query_dict).distinct()`

Is there any way I can create the same thing in node js. Is there any module which will work the same as Django DB.

Or how Django works internally to create dynamic query

Comment: Did you find answer to your question?

Comment: Yes. Used sequelize ORM in NodeJS